# Aggregating information and Bayesian information

Tags: bayesian, normal-distribution, stochastic-processes, state-space-models

Consider a binary random variable $\theta\in\{0,1\}$. I refer to this variable as "the state". Further assume that each possible state happens with equal probability (i.e., equal to $1/2$). I cannot observe this state, however I have access to a sample $\{r_i(\theta)\}_{i=1}^n$. This sample constitutes the realization of a random variable $R_i(\theta)$, which is distributed according to the following equation:

$$R_i(\theta)=\begin{cases}
p^A\cdot u_A-c+\varepsilon_i &\text{if} \quad \theta=1\\
(1-p^A)\cdot u_B-c+\varepsilon_i &\text{if} \quad \theta=0\\
\end{cases}$$

where $\varepsilon_i\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1/\rho_{\epsilon^2})$ and all the other variables are deterministic. Notice that in some sense I would like to have no noise term and observe the "true" realisations but I instead only have access to noisy realizations of $R_i$, which I denote $r_i$.

My question is then the following: **Can  I use my sample $\{r_i\}_{i=1}^n$ in order to infer the true state of the world $\theta$?** In some Bayesian sense, I was thinking about updating in the following way:

$$\mathbb{P}(\theta=1|\text{observing sample } r_i(\theta))=\frac{\mathbb{P}(L(r_i|\theta=1)) \mathbb{P}(\theta=1)}{L(r_i|\theta=1) \mathbb{P}(\theta=1)+L(r_i|\theta=0) \mathbb{P}(\theta=0)}$$

where $L(r_i|\theta=1)$ is some sort of "likelihood" of observing the sample $r_i(\theta)$ given the state of the world. *I am being very loose here, but essentially I am interested in computing the probability of this underlying state*. What do you think? Do you have any suggestions on how to compute $\mathbb{P}(\theta=1|\text{observing sample } r_i(\theta))$?

Comment: You say nothing of how R relates to your mixture model. If they're independent the "probabilities" factor. (Note: $\lambda_i$ is not an event thus does not have a probability). Also what is the event "Observing R"? Are you referring to $P(R=r)$?

Comment: Ok, I added some comments in the post. Sorry about being not very rigorous with the probability concepts, I need to brush-up a bit, but I hope that my idea gets trough.

Comment: You were missing a close paren, "$)$", in the numerator of your fraction. I put it where I think you meant it. Please ensure that it still says what you want it to say.

Comment: If I read correctly, there are only two possible distributions your sample could be drawn from, both normal, they have the same variance, and you can exactly calculate their mean. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, exactly! @Jonny Lomond